# Ruby - Reading a file causes an extra line while printing

Tags: ruby, file

How can I avoid a new line when I use `puts line + "test"`

Example code:

```
  File.open("test.txt", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      puts line + "test" #=>line1\ntest
      #puts "test" + line #=> testline1
    end
  end
```

When I use:

```
puts "test" + line`
```

It shows:

```
testline1
```

(`line1` being the only thing in the `test.txt`)

However,

```
puts line + "test"
```

looks like:

```
test
line1
```

Is there anyway of stopping it from producing the extra line?

Comment: This is very typical when reading from a file. It will pick up the end of the line (i.e. new line) and pass that with the line. Just parse it by adding `.chomp` at the end.  In your case: `puts line.chomp + "test"`

Comment: Instead of opening the file then using `each_line`, use `foreach`. It will simplify and reduce your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to strip out the newline, use String#chomp to take care of it.

http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/String/chomp

```
puts line.chomp + "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) to strip out all the *leading* and *trailing* whitespace characters (including new line):

```
puts line.strip + "test"
# => line1test
```

To delete only the *trailing* whitespaces, you can use [String#rstrip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-rstrip):

```
puts line.rstrip + "test"
# => line1test
```

Comment: While `strip` will strip the trailing white space, it also removes leading white space, which is often significant. A better choice is `rstrip` which only works on the end of the string.